# MSwM (Markov-Switching Model) function in R not working

Tags: r, r-package

I am trying to run the function below in order to create a Markov-Switching Model according to [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MSwM/MSwM.pdf).

```
olsY = model.matrix(persons ~ vocMean + ble + cal + weekday, model.frame(lm(persons ~ vocMean + ble + cal + weekday, data = data)))

msY = msmFit(olsY, k = 2, sw = rep(TRUE, 5))
```

But the second line of code gives me the following error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘msmFit’ for signature ‘"matrix", "numeric", "logical", "missing", "missing", "missing"’
```

Can someone please help me fix this issue? Thank you very much.
The data I used is [here](https://github.com/aifb/eshl-occupancy).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your OLS specification is too complex: olsY in msmFit should belong to (g)lm or "formula" class, so just rewrite your first part of code in this way

```
olsY = lm(persons ~ vocMean + ble + cal + weekday, data = data)
```